# Why is the nature of graph of utility function different from indifference curve?

Tags: utility, preferences

I am new to Economics, but I have this doubt. The indifference curve and utility function both have the same equation, so their graph must also be similar, which is true I guess. Then why is it that the nature of graphs are different? I mean why is it that if the indifference curve is convex then utility function is quasi concave?  How did we arrive at this conclusion?

Comment: You can refer to https://qr.ae/TWvVSr for answer.

Comment: @Amit [Link only answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)

Comment: It may be worth your time asking a separate question concerning the relationship between quasi-concave utility functions and their convex contour curves (indifference curves). Although I found [this answer](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/26498/if-a-utility-function-is-quasi-concave-can-we-say-that-the-ic-curve-associated) written by @Giskard as well.

Comment: @Brennan That friggin' Giskard person is everywhere, dude...

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be confusing some things.

> The indifference curve and utility function both have the same
>   equation

The utility function has a formula, not an equation.

$U(x_1,x_2)$ is a utility function.

The points $(x_1,x_2)$ for which $U(x_1,x_2) = 13$ form an indifference curve. (13 was picked as a random number)

The graph of a utility function has one more dimension than the graph of an indifference curve: in addition to the space of goods, this graph would also include the utility value, so its points would be something like $(x_1,x_2,u)$. Chances are you have not seen a graph of any such function, as 3D drawings are complicated. This is why maps of 2D indifference curves are used to get a feeling for the shapes of utility functions.

Answer (score 1):

Utility functions and indifference curves are the same object considered from different visual/conceptual angles. Below an illustration on $U(x_1, x_2) = x_1^{0.5} x_2^{0.5}$ (representing *Cobb-Douglas preferences*), done with excel:

[image]