# Does quasi-concave utility function imply convex indifference curve?

Tags: microeconomics, utility

It is well-known that convex indifference curve (i.e. the function is convex)/ preference would imply quasi-concave utility function. But does quasi-concave utility function imply convex indifference curve?

It seems that [this answer](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/26498/if-a-utility-function-is-quasi-concave-can-we-say-that-the-ic-curve-associated) give a brief sketch of the proof, but how can I show it in a more formal way?

Comment: Seems like that answer had little effect, because I tried to point out in it that the indifference curve is usually not "convex".

Comment: Your question seems fairly straightforward. Have you tried directly applying the definitions of convex preferences and quasi-concave utility functions?

Comment: You said that "What you probably mean is that the IC curve implicitly defines a convex function f where f(x)=y." That is what I meant. I am not sure what do you mean by " IC curve is not convex in the usual meaning of the word convex when applied to sets".

Comment: I know how to go from quasi-concave utility function to convex preference now. But what about from convex preference to convex indifference curve (formally)?

Comment: Would you mind typing in your quasi-concave utility function to convex preference proof (edit your question, do not add more comments), so we can see why it is not reversible?

Comment: On convexity: Most curves are not convex sets. If you pick two points from the curve you can usually find a convex combination of them that is not on the curve.

Comment: I never said that it is not reversible. I just wonder how to prove that convex preference leads to convex indifference curve.

Comment: Would you please give us your definition of a quasi-concave function? In some cases, the claim is true by definition.

Comment: The definition is the same as the one here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiconvex_function

Comment: "Convex" indifference curves does not imply quasiconcave utility function. Consider $u = -xy$, $u$ has convex ICs but it is not quasiconcave.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does quasi-concave utility function imply convex indifference curve?

No that is not true. Consider $u(x, y) = -x^2 - y^2$ defined on $\mathbb{R}^2_+$. Since $u$ is concave it is quasiconcave. Observing the graph of the indifference curves, we see that ICs of $u$ are not "convex".

[image]

Comment: The answer linked in the question does say that monotonicity is required. You are right that this information is not contained in the body of this question.